# White space between inline-block elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-lists

I feel like this question shouldn't exist anymore, but I can't seem to find a solution. So here goes.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width:150px;
}
ul.nav_sub_menu > li {
    width: 100%;
}

ul.nav_sub_menu > li a {
    display: inline-block;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 2.5px 0px 2.5px 5px;

    background: #213059;

    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;

    border-bottom: 5px solid #253767;
}

ul.nav_sub_menu > li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #253767;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_sub_menu_wrapper">
 <ul class="nav_sub_menu">
  <li>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_sub_button">About me</a></li><li>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_sub_button">Goals</a></li><li>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_sub_button">Realizations</a></li><li>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav_sub_button">Future plans</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This example generates a styles list with `display:inline-block` anchor tags
You might notice from the start that each list-item is separated by a horizontal white line between them. If not, try zooming the browser in or out (visible at 110% for me).

The white space isn't visible at all zoom levels and it only happens in Chrome, that's why I am at a loss.
How does one begin to troubleshoot this?

[image]

FYI, I have found [this link](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) to be useful but it didn't help. My chrome version:

> Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Comment: Is this just happening when you zoom out to 110% right?

Comment: No on my dev machine it happens at multiple zoom levels, within the code generator in SO it happens at 110% for me (chrome only, of course)

Comment: The size of the browser makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a weird issue. I think it might be something to do with the pixel resolution or density perhaps. However I managed to fix it with the below code.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width:150px;
}
ul.nav_sub_menu > li {
    width: 100%;
}

ul.nav_sub_menu > li a {
    display: inline-block;

    width: 100%;
    padding: 2.5px 0px 2.5px 5px;

    background: #213059;

    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;

    border-bottom: 5px solid #253767;
    float: left;
}

ul.nav_sub_menu > li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #253767;
}
```

All I added was `float: left;` to the anchor property and it removed the white line between the list items. Try it and see what it does for different zoom levels. Although it does work for *110% zoom* for me.

Comment: That did it. It's a weird issue but I hand't considered floating because it feels like a hack. I'm trying to avoid it as much as possible for learning purposes. Well... bump!